# `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` when trying to generate a random number

Tags: python, numpy

```
test = np.random.randn(0, 0.25)
```

I'm trying to generate a random number with a mean of 0 and variance of 0.25.

When I run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [np.random.normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

Comment: @BigBobey The function you showed does not accept floats [`numpy.random.randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [numpy.random.randn()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) generates random numbers from the [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution) (This is a special case when mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1).

To generate a random number based on defined mean and standard deviation, use the method [np.random.normal()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html).

```
test = np.random.normal(0, 0.25)
```